# Как отправить POST запрос?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Хочу на чужой сайт отправить POST запрос, делаю вот так

```
fetch(event.target.form.action, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({iggid: 984381625, cdkey: 'V4CPTV'}),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Но проблема с кросс заголовком, я не могу отправить POST запрос

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обойти через iframe? У меня есть массив ключей и нужно их отправить одним запросом

Comment: Покажите ошибку которая у вас появляется

Comment: Если проблема с CORS и сайт на который вы отправляете запрос вам не принадлежит, то 2 варианта:
1) Измените запрос так чтобы он соответствовал CORS
2) Сайт защищён от внешних запросов - тогда увы, вы не отправите запрос.